# UITableView with clickable, sortable headers

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I'm trying to take an existing UITableView and add column headers which are clickable and sortable. I've looked at AQGridView but I can't see a way to get that sort of effect. At the moment I'm thinking of adding a UIButton above the UITableView then styling it to make it look like a header. Is this an awful idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the iPhone there is not really enough space to do desktop program style column sorting.

The recommended way to to this is to put a `UISegmentedControl` as the `titleView` of the `UINavigationBar` or a `UIToolBar`.

Looks pretty, too.

Comment: As the header of a UITableView works just fine, you just need to wire up the segment changed action in IB.

Comment: The problem with the `tableHeaderView` of the `UITableView` though is that it will scroll off the screen.